# installing kali linux on live usb

Tags: usb, kali-linux

I would like to divide a USB into three partitions.

1. The first in FAT32 to use for data, photos, etc. compatible with windows, linux and mac osx.
2. The second contains the Live Usb of Kali to boot from Bios.
3. The third containing the persistence.

I have tried various ways; however, when I set Kali as `SDC1`, Windows reads the first partition, and tells me that I have to format, finding no other partitions.

When i set the partition in `FAT32` as `SDC1` and I try to access Kali by Bios, if the `FAT32` partition is empty Kali starts without problems, if the `FAT32` partition contains some files it starts Windows instead of Kali.

I installed Kali from Linux with `dd` with another key that I have.

I tried to solve this problem for two days, but I can't figure out what to do.

system:
MacBook Pro mid 2012 i5 ram 8g

OS: Mac OSX and Windows 7

Usb: SanDisk 32gb

P.S. I do not need a program on Windows that let me read all the partitions, I need Windows to just mount the `FAT32` partition and have Kali boot when requested from the BIOS.

Comment: When you are using dd what exactly are you passing? Also, on linux, what is the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`?

Comment: i wrote "dd if=kali.iso(image of kali) of=dev/sdc1(my usb) bs 512k"   the same things that the tutorial in the kali's official sites says

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your bootloader which lives in the first 512B of the iso.

To solve this, use `fdisk /dev/sdc` and set partition 2 to be bootable.

When you're using `dd` try the following `dd if=kali.img of=/dev/sdc2 bs=512K skip=512`. `grub` might get clobbered, but you can always reinstalled grub with [`grub-install /dev/sdc2`](http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter08/grub.html); **however**, I'd try it before doing that.